# Woocommerce Custom affiliate link with multi URLs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I currently run a site which has products in Woocommerce. The product URL links to an affiliate site and the custom `functions.php` script appends the affiliate ID to the extenal URL using this code:

```
 *  Custom Add Affiliate link to Buy Product
 */
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'custom_product_add_to_cart_url', 20, 2 );
function custom_product_add_to_cart_url( $add_to_cart_url, $product ){
    if( $product->is_type('external') )
        $add_to_cart_url .= '/?affiliateID-1';

    return $add_to_cart_url;
}
/**
 *  End Custom Add Affiliate link to Buy Product
```

What I am hoping to do is add another affilate site to this and depending which URL is in the `$add_to_cart_url` would determine which affiliate link is appended.

So currently if the `$add_to_cart_url` is **[www.siteA.com](http://www.siteA.com)** the link generated is **[www.siteA.com/?affiliateID-1](http://www.siteA.com/?affiliateID-1)**

I want to make a change so that:
 
 if the `$add_to_cart_url` is **[www.siteA.com](http://www.siteA.com)** the link generated is **[www.siteA.com/?affiliateID-1](http://www.siteA.com/?affiliateID-1)**  
 ***OR*** 
  if the `$add_to_cart_url` is **[www.siteB.net](http://www.siteB.net)** the link generated is **[www.siteB.net/?affiliateID-2](http://www.siteB.net/?affiliateID-2)**

I assume I need some form of "if `$add_to_cart_url` is this, then append with this, else append with this" however I'm not sure how I need to adjust my existing code to do this.

I'm hoping someone out there can help me.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a second if statement within the  `if( $product->is_type('external') )` block. You would need to assign a value to the $add_to_cart first to check what if it holds the SiteA or SiteB value etc. Then check that within the if statement, like so: (This will need changing to suit your argument)

```
    $add_to_cart = $someValueHere;

    if ($add_to_cart == $siteAValue){

        $add_to_cart_url .= '/?affiliateID-1';

    } else if ($add_to_cart == $siteBValue){
        
        $add_to_cart_url .= '/?affiliateID-2';
    }
        

    return $add_to_cart_url;
}
```

Comment: I think this could be heading the right way with what I want to do. It’s the content of the add_to_cart part that needs to check if it contains part of a specific URL for each. That url is set in product page. Where should I be entering the specifics of each of the 2 urls it needs to check against? 

Maybe if for example Facebook.com is affiliate 1 and Microsoft.com is affiliate 2? Would you be able to show an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can even hide the add to cart button and add a custom one and work with it.

For the product page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', function () {
    global $product;
    if( $product->is_type('external') ) {
        echo '<a href="YOUR-URL/?affiliateID-1">Affiliate Button</a>';
    }
}, 30 );
```

Or like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', function () {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('external') ) {
        
        $link = 'YOUR-URL/?affiliateID-1'; // <== Here set button link
        $name = 'Affiliate Button'; // <== Here set button name 
        $class = 'button alt';
        $style = 'display: inline-block; margin-top: 12px;';
    
        // Output
        echo ' <a href="'.$link.'" class="'.$class.'" style="'.$style.'">'.$name.'</a>';
    }
}, 20 );
```